# How to divide a block into smaller blocks of 4?

Tags: algorithm

I want to divide a block into n number of smaller blocks, grouped in 4s. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if I should be using a loop or recursion of some sort but the rules of the algorithm would be something like:

- if 1 dont split
- if 2 split in half
- if 3 split in half and then split 1 of the halves in half again
- if 4 split in half and then split both halves in half again
- if 5 split in half and then split both halves in half again then
  split one of the quarters in half
- etc

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the *quadtree*?

Comment: Maybe? Are you able to help with an answer?

Comment: No, not really.  First issue: I don't want to spend the time it would take me to write a good explanation. Second: quad trees are well known and the web, and textbooks, are full of good descriptions and probably code too if you look carefully. Third: by your own admission you are not sure a quad tree is what you are looking for, so you need to do some more research yourself.

Comment: @grabury It seems like you kind of know what you need to do. Your decision steps are clear, and yes, recursion would be a nice way to solve this. If it's the implementation you are unsure about, I recommend looking into [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) in general. As mentioned above, you will probably arrive at some form quadtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with a queue -- iteratively -- much like you would do with a breadth-first traversal. A bit specific is that you want a block to be first split into 4 smaller blocks before moving to another block. So that means you'll have a loop over a fifo-queue (deque) in which one block will be popped from the deque, and three smaller ones will be pushed unto it. Only when the number of splits becomes less than 3, you'll have to produce fewer blocks.

Below you'll find a runnable JavaScript implementation, where the blocks are represented by instances of a `Rectangle` class (with coordinates of the top-left corner, and its dimensions). A split will create from one instance two new instances. This snippet will draw each rectangle once the requested number of splits have been performed:

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(left, top, width, height) {
        Object.assign(this, {left, top, width, height});
    }
    splitVertically() {
        const width = this.width / 2;
        return [
            new Rectangle(this.left, this.top, width, this.height),
            new Rectangle(this.left + width, this.top, width, this.height)
        ];
    }
    splitHorizontally() {
        const height = this.height / 2;
        return [
            new Rectangle(this.left, this.top, this.width, height),
            new Rectangle(this.left, this.top + height, this.width, height)
        ];
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.rect(this.left+0.5, this.top+0.5, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function splitBlock(n, rect) {
    let deque = [rect];
    while (n-- > 0) {
        const rect = deque.shift();
        const arr = rect.splitVertically();
        if (n-- > 0) arr.push(...arr.shift().splitHorizontally());
        if (n-- > 0) arr.push(...arr.shift().splitHorizontally());
        deque.push(...arr);
    }
    return deque;
}

// Example run
const numSplits = 11;
const blocks = splitBlock(numSplits, new Rectangle(0, 0, 180, 180))
// Output the result on a canvas
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
for (const block of blocks) block.draw(ctx);
```

```html
<canvas width="181" height="181"></canvas>
```